# CQL : .InvalidQueryException: Invalid amount of bind variables

Tags: cassandra, apache-camel

I am trying to query Cassandra Db from camel-context. Below is the route:

```
<route id="cassendraroute">
   <from uri="direct:routecassendra"/>
   <to uri="cql://127.0.0.1/empdetails?cql=select * from employee;&amp;prepareStatements=false "/>
</route>
```

I am facing the below exception:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid amount of bind variables at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java

Can someone let me know the exact syntax for Cassandra camel component ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<to uri="cql:0.0.0.0:9042/keyspace_name?cql=Select * from table_name where primary_key_column=?"/>
```

You can substitute the IP and port as per your setup (default port is 9042 though). Also keyspace_name, table_name and primary_key_column you can set as per your data structure.

Comment: As suggested, i implemented routed as  
<to uri="cql:127.0.0.1:9042/empdetails?cql=select * from employee where id=2"/>
but facing below exception :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prepared statement has only 0 variables, 1 values provided
 at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.bind(BoundStatement.java:140)[556:com.datastax.driver.core:2.1.5]

Answer (score 0):

Today I was bad hit by this and any workaround changed the problem from "Invalid amount of bind variables" to "Prepared statement has only 0 variables" as Alexis commented.

The solution I found was:

```js
 .split(body()).streaming()
 .doTry()
 .setHeader("CamelCqlQuery", simple("${body}"))
 .setBody().simple("${null}")
 .toD("cql:"+cassandra_ips+"/"+cassandra_keyspace)
```

In my case I had a splitter because I was running batches. I need a list of statements in the body to iterate over it, so I couldn't just make it null.